# CoreBluetooth peripheral.name is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, swift2, core-bluetooth

I just want to have the list of nearby Bluetooth devices' names. However, peripheral.name is always nil. The name in Advertising package is also always nil. I have 7 devices nearby. I can see them but not their names.

I am using Swift2.0 and XCode7.

My code is as  follows (I added CoreBluetooth.framework as well):

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var blueToothReady = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startUpCentralManager()
    }

    func startUpCentralManager() {
        print("Initializing central manager")
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func discoverDevices() {
        print("discovering devices")
        centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
        // centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : NSNumber(bool: true)])

    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
        let nameOfDeviceFound = (advertisementData as NSDictionary).objectForKey(CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) as? NSString
        print("\(nameOfDeviceFound)")
        print("Discovered \(peripheral.name)")
    }


    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Connected to a peripheral")
    }


    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
        print("Failed to connect to peripheral")
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
        print("Disconnected from Peripheral")
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : AnyObject]) {
        print("Will restore state")
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        print("checking state")
        switch (central.state) {
        case .PoweredOff:
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off")

        case .PoweredOn:
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready")
            blueToothReady = true;

        case .Resetting:
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is resetting")

        case .Unauthorized:
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized")

        case .Unknown:
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");

        case .Unsupported:
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");

        }
        if blueToothReady {
            discoverDevices()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you see the name of the same device in iPhone Bluetooth setting?

Comment: Does the name show in a Bluetooth Low Energy sniffer (like LightBlue)? And what kind of devices are you testing with?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I can see names in iPhone bluetooth settings. I cannot see the names in LightBlue.

Comment: BTW: I have bluetooth speakers, other iphones, ipads etc. as nearby bluetooth devices.